# Count of values in one column based on another column

Tags: arrays, matlab, octave

I have a table with two columns like so:

```
1  10 
1  10 
2  30 
2  45 
3  8 
3  8 
....
```

How can I (in Matlab or Octave) count the number of different values—that is, the number of unique values in the second column for each value in the first column—and show the following?

```
1 1
2 2
3 1
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take the [tour] and read up on [ask]. First up: MATLAB is not Octave. Don't use both tags unless you're explicitly asking about the differences or similarities between the two, see the "learn more..." tabs in [tag:matlab]  and [tag:octave]. Second: Please clarify your question. Why isn't 10, 30 or 45 counted? What do you actually want to count? Also, it's appreciated if you show your own effort, either in thoughts/algorithms or actual (non-working) code, a [mcve]. Please [edit] the question accordingly.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a few steps

1. Find all unique rows, i.e. unique combinations of both columns. The `unique` function has an option to do this

   ```
   c = unique( a, 'rows' );
   ```
2. Find the unique values in column 1, these are the first column of your ouput

   ```
   u = unique( c(:,1) );
   ```
3. Loop over the unique values in `u`, and check how many rows match in column 1 of `c` (i.e. how many unique combinations use this first value in the input `a`). You can use `arrayfun` to do this in a condensed way, or a simple loop would work

   ```
   n = arrayfun( @(x) nnz(x==c(:,1)), u );
   ```

Now you can get the desired output by combining `u` and `n`

```
out = [u, n];
```

This gives the desired result for your example

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach using [`unique`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/double.unique.html) and [`accumarray`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/accumarray.html):

```
x = [1 10; 1 10; 2 30; 2 45; 3 8; 3 8];
[u, ~, w] = unique(x(:,1));
n = accumarray(w, x(:,2), [], @(t) numel(unique(t)));
result = [u n];
```